# Cannot install apps from google play store

Tags: applications, google-play-store, alternative-markets

I am using Samsung Galaxy Y, Android version 2.3.6 only, I rooted it yesterday and now I could not install apps from google play store. And as device memory is small so I think it's better if I download apps straight from websites. Is there any trustworthy and user friendly website for this? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Using the Play Store or a website will change the amount of space apps take. If you are looking for a trustworthly, meaning relatively safe, alternative to the Play Store, consider F-Droid. https://f-droid.org/

Comment: Also take a look at our [alternative-markets tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/alternative-markets/info). As @acejavelin correctly pointed out, apps taking up the same space regardless of where they are downloaded from – but of course you might save a little space by disabling the Playstore app, uninstalling its updates, and clearing its cache/data. F-Droid is a good address indeed (and I have a compatible [App-Repo](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo) for it even). Not that huge collection of apps, though.

Answer (score 1):

there're manyy third party stores.
Visit http://choilieng.com to get ur apk file . It looks quite simple but this will help you load faster.

Have fun./

Answer (score 0):

There are many alternates of Google Play Store. Here is the list:

- Amazon App Store
- [ApkMirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/)
- AppBrain: If you are looking for premium apps for free, this is your destination.
- [Opera Mobile Store](http://apps.opera.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Use  [apkmirror](http://www.apkmirror.com)  It looks quite simple and trust